# Ng-Model inside Ng-Repeat (not a binding to primitive type issue)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

** Edit: my apologies my first example was not representative of the code that I have.

After hours and hours of research and testing I am finally resorting to this.

The problem is:  I am unable to update a model on my controllers scope from inside the child-scope of my ng-repeat.  I am not iterating over primitives, as that seems to be the common cause of this issue,  further more, upon trying to replicate my problem in repl's what I am doing seems to work... Any help would be much appreciated.

I am currently using Angular 1.2.16

First:  A Working example in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d25f727ZqJYn3cwUQNby)

Second: The broken code

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myController', [ '$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.object = {
        description: '',
        config: { 
            game_type: ''
        }
    };

    $scope.data = { 
        'game_types': [
            {'key': 'meow', 'val': 2},
            {'key': 'meow1', 'val': 3},
            {'key': 'meow2', 'val': 4}
        ]
    };
}]);
```

HTML // this snippit IS wrapped in an ng-app, its just not included

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <h4>Description</h4> 
      <input class="form-control" ng-model="object.description" placeholder="Enter a Description" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <h4>Contest Type</h4>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <div data-toggle="buttons">
            <label ng-repeat="type in data.game_types" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
              <input ng-model="object.description" type="radio" name="game_type" ng-value="type.val">{{ type.key }}
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried referencing the parent scope directly from inside the ng-repeat (although I don't think I should have to given my data), but to no avail.

I am very confused.  From all my research this should be totally fine. And as linked, works in practice.

I am only posting a separate issue because of the weirdness I am experiencing, and because previous suggestions, largely around how scopes work and binding to primitives, do not seem the be the issue.

Thanks very much for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

It looks like you just used the wrong binding for the radio button.  Instead of binding to `object.description`, you probably meant to bind to `object.config.game_type`:

```
<input ng-model="object.config.game_type" type="radio" ng-value="type.val">
...
```

[Here is an update](http://plnkr.co/edit/SNV2TrCkjhmilC7B0Aty?p=preview) to your plunkr, showing that the binding is working.

---

**Old answer**

`ng-controller` only applies to the element you add it to, and any nested elements.  So these are all that are covered:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <h4>Description</h4> 
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="object.description" placeholder="Enter a Description" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

For the rest of your elements to work, add `ng-controller` to a surrounding element, such as `body`.

Comment: sorry, this was my mistake, my first post was not representative of the code that I have.

Answer (score 0):

Derp. Bootstrap events were not ever toggling the input, thus nothing ever changed. >.<

Lesson learned, bootstrap JS and angular do not play well together.  Using angular-ui-bootstrap and everything is now wonderful.